# Python - Formatting a print to align a specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, tuples

I am trying to format a print statement to align a specific column.

Currently my output is:

```
0 - Rusty Bucket (40L bucket - quite rusty) = $0.00
1 - Golf Cart (Tesla powered 250 turbo) = $195.00*
2 - Thermomix (TM-31) = $25.50*
3 - AeroPress (Great coffee maker) = $5.00
4 - Guitar (JTV-59) = $12.95
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
0 - Rusty Bucket (40L bucket - quite rusty)    = $0.00
1 - Golf Cart (Tesla powered 250 turbo)        = $195.00*
2 - Thermomix (TM-31)                          = $25.50*
3 - AeroPress (Great coffee maker)             = $5.00
4 - Guitar (JTV-59)                            = $12.95
```

Here is the code I am currently using for the print:

```
def list_items():
    count = 0
    print("All items on file (* indicates item is currently out):")
    for splitline in all_lines:
        in_out = splitline[3]
        dollar_sign = "= $"
        daily_price = "{0:.2f}".format(float(splitline[2]))
        if in_out == "out":
            in_out = str("*")
        else:
            in_out = str("")
        print(count, "- {} ({}) {}{}{}".format(splitline[0], splitline[1], dollar_sign, daily_price, in_out))
        count += 1
```

I have tried using formatting such as:

```
print(count, "- {:>5} ({:>5}) {:>5}{}{}".format(splitline[0], splitline[1], dollar_sign, daily_price, in_out))
```

but have never been able to get just the one column to align. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I am also using python 3.x

To note I am using tuples to contain all the information, with `all_lines` being the master list, as it were. The information is being read from a csv originally. Apologies for the horrible naming conventions, trying to work on functionality first.

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere; I have tried looking.

EDIT: Here is the code im using for my all_lines

```
import csv
open_file = open('items.csv', 'r+')
all_lines = []
for line in open_file:
    splitline = line.strip().split(',')
    all_lines.append((splitline[0], splitline[1], splitline[2], splitline[3]))
```

And here is the csv file information:

```
Rusty Bucket,40L bucket - quite rusty,0.0,in
Golf Cart,Tesla powered 250 turbo,195.0,out
Thermomix,TM-31,25.5,out
AeroPress,Great coffee maker,5.0,in
Guitar,JTV-59,12.95,in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for may be:

[EDIT] I have now also included a tabulate version since you may gain flexibility with this.

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
open_file = open('items.csv', 'r+')
all_lines = []
for line in open_file:
    splitline = line.strip().split(',')
    all_lines.append((splitline[0], splitline[1], splitline[2], splitline[3]))

#print all_lines
count = 0
new_lines=[]
for splitline in all_lines:
    in_out = splitline[3]
    dollar_sign = "= $"
    daily_price = "{0:.2f}".format(float(splitline[2]))
    if in_out == "out":
        in_out = str("*")
    else:
        in_out = str("")
    str2='('+splitline[1]+')'    
    print count, "- {:<30} {:<30} {}{:<30} {:<10}".format(splitline[0], str2, dollar_sign, daily_price, in_out)
    new_lines.append([splitline[0], str2, dollar_sign, daily_price, in_out])
    count += 1

print tabulate(new_lines, tablefmt="plain")
print
print tabulate(new_lines, tablefmt="plain", numalign="left")
```

Comment: This is working a treat, the only thing that I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this without me specifying each all_lines.append(). Because I am working with a program that will be adding extra lines in, so i need it to be able to display the additional content!! Cheers for the speedy reply!

Comment: I have only used that all_line statement because I do not know where your data comes from, and how it looks like, so I have taken the printout you attached and constructed an all_lines from it. I assumed that your all_line already has the format which I am generating in the first three lines. Can you specify your all_lines in more detail? Have you tried just to skip my first three lines and use you all_lines?

Comment: Certainly, my all_lines currently looks like this:
    open_file = open('items.csv', 'r+')
    all_lines = []
    for line in open_file:
        splitline = line.strip().split(',')
        all_lines.append((splitline[0], splitline[1], splitline[2], splitline[3]))

I am pulling the information from a csv file.

Comment: I suggest that you put that code into your original post above, editing that original post. Can you copy part of your csv file into your post? What are the columns in your csv file?

Comment: Edited the original post to contain the information you asked for.

Comment: Please try the modified code above. It is important to attach the '(' and ')' brackets to your string in advance of the formatting line, otherwise blanks get inserted inside the string, this is why I have used the str2 variable.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks so much for taking the time. Also thanks for clearing up the (' and ') brackets for me.

Comment: You are welcome: I have nevertheless also added a tabulate version in the code, maybe that works for you with some more flexibility (e.g. using optimal column widths)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`str.ljust(width[, fillchar])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```
> '(TM-31)'.ljust(15)
'(TM-31)        '  # pad to width
```

Then extract the variable-length `{} ({})` part and padd it to the necessary width.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the idea of controlling printing format myself.

In this case, I would leverage a tabulating library such as: [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

The two key points are:

1. keep data in a table (e.g. list in a list)
2. select proper printing format with `tablefmt` param.